# How to get data from file in the same folder as a JS variable in a background page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So my question is this: i have a box.html that contains some `<div>`s. It is way too big to be stored as a string in the background script. It would be very inconvenient to change anything in the html if it was stored as just a string variable.

What I can't figure out is how to access that file from background.js so that all of the html is then stored in a variable like `var box = "some html"`

So that when I have that variable I can then pass it on to a content script when I need it.

I know that `chrome.extension.getURL('box.html');` gets the path to the file I need, but how do I load the file?

in Firefox this is simply done with: `self.data.load('box.html');` in the main.js 
so is there a similar call for google chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a simple ajax request through jQuery to solve this in the past:

```
var myDiv = document.queryElement('my_div');

$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('box.html'), function(data) {
  myDiv.innerHTML = data;
});
```

Comment: That did it, and also adding the box.html to web_accessible_resources